# swiftUI AVPlayer adding time observer causes the screen to freeze

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayer

I have a music player app, using swiftUI to build the interface, MusicPlayerVM is similar to this,

```
class MusicPlayer: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    let player: AVPlayer = {
    
    let _player = AVPlayer()
    
    _player.volume = 2.0
    
    return _player
    
}()
deinit(){...}
init(){...}


@Published var progress : Double = .zero
var timeObserver: Any?

func currentTimeAddObserver() {

        self.timeObserver = self.player.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1),queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] (time) in
        
        guard let `self` = self else{ return }
        
        
        if self.isSeekingToTime {
            return
        }
      self.progress = CMTimeGetSeconds(time)
       }

   }

func removeObserver() {

.........

}
```

}

add every second observation to update the playback progress whenever it starts playing, stored in published progress: Double = ** , swiftUI passes this progress Update the SliderBar, this should look fine. But whenever adding observations will cause me to stutter while swiping。

[*This is screen recording *](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17onSpV2iExyJVWIo_W5CsRTwyEOGOA55/view?usp=sharing)

I have expressions on the picture. It's worth noting that if I remove the observer, or pause playback, or change the published var to a var, the problem goes away, but it prevents me from updating the view. I checked the information on the Internet but it doesn't seem to have the same situation as me, please advise

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.